# How to convert BASE64 string into Image with Flutter?

Tags: image, list, base64, converters, flutter

I'm converting images saved in my Firebase database to Base64 and would like to decode and encode.  I've researched similar questions, but am still getting errors.  Here is what I have so far?

```
var image1 = String;

var pic = event.snapshot.value['image'];
var photo = BASE64.decode(pic);
image1 = photo;
```

I'm getting the following error...

`A value of type "List<int>" cannot be assigned to a variable of type "Type"`

If you could please provide a reverse process for encoding an image into Base64 so they may be saved back to Firebase, that would be appreciated.

*** UPDATE

Here is my updated code that's still throwing an error.

```
image1 = event.snapshot.value['image'];
var image = BASE64.decode(image1.toString());
new Image.memory(image),
```

The error is...

`FormatException: Invalid Length must be a multiple of 4`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can convert a `Uint8List` to a Flutter `Image` widget using the [`Image.memory`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html) constructor. (Use the [`Uint8List.fromList`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html) constructor to convert a `List` to `Uint8List` if necessary.) You can use `BASE64.encode` to go the other way.

Here's some sample code.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData.dark(),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _base64;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    (() async {
      http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://flutter.io/images/flutter-mark-square-100.png',
      );
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _base64 = BASE64.encode(response.bodyBytes);
        });
      }
    })();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_base64 == null)
      return new Container();
    Uint8List bytes = BASE64.decode(_base64);
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Example App')),
      body: new ListTile(
        leading: new Image.memory(bytes),
        title: new Text(_base64),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, it's generally a bad idea to store large blobs of binary data in your database. It's not playing to the strengths of Firebase realtime database and you will end up wasting bandwidth transmitting data you don't need as well as unnecessary encoding and decoding. You should use the [`firebase_storage`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_storage) plugin instead, storing the path or download URL of the image in the database.

Comment: Got it.  Now its says `Uint8ClampedList cannot be assigned to variable Uint8List`?  Please explain

Comment: When I run this `new Image.memory(photo.toList()),` My app breaks and I get the following error `Format Exception: Invalid Length, must be multiple of 4`  Please help

Comment: Please update your question with the code you're using, because I don't see a call to `toList()`. It sounds like you're directly calling `toList()` on a `String`, which will produce a `List` of base64 characters. This list isn't a binary representation of the decoded image, so that's probably why you're running into an error when it can't be rendered. Convert the decoded image (the output of `decode()`) to a Uint8List using `new Uint8List.fromList()`.

Comment: That said, I would strongly suggest you try firebase_storage, it is a much better approach than storing base64 encoded images in a database.

Comment: Thanks @CollinJackson , The problem is that I currently have an iOS Swift app that I'm updating where I've saved user photos with Base64.  There's only a few users but I would like to allow them to access their photos and if they change them then save them and new ones to `FirebaseStorage`.  I've updated the question with my new results.

Comment: I updated my answer with sample code. The base64 encoding and decoding seems to work fine, so I think something is wrong with the database handling code. Can you print out the value of `image1.toString()` and put it in your question so that I can test with the same image?

Comment: Collin I'm having trouble again.  See if you can turn this BASE64 string into an image.  It's just a placeholder until my user uploads a  photo `SW1hZ2UoaW1hZ2U6IEFzc2V0SW1hZ2UoYnVuZGxlOiBudWxsLCBuYW1lOiAiYXNzZXRzL3BsYWNlaG9sZGVyLnBuZyIpLCBhbGlnbm1lbnQ6IEFsaWdubWVudC5jZW50ZXIp`

Comment: Is this possible to save gif in sqflite with this way?

Comment: Converted successfully but image not getting proper when I decoded base64 to image online? any idea how can I get proper image

Comment: You can also use Uint8List bytes =
        Base64Decoder().convert(base64Text); if you get an error while trying to use BASE64.decode()

Answer (score 108):

There's a simpler way using `'dart:convert'` package

```
Image.memory(base64Decode(base64String));
```

Implementation and some useful methods :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';


Image imageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
  return Image.memory(base64Decode(base64String));
}

Uint8List dataFromBase64String(String base64String) {
  return base64Decode(base64String);
}

String base64String(Uint8List data) {
  return base64Encode(data);
}
```

Comment: `The method 'memory' isn't defined for the type 'Image'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'memory'.`   ... I'm finding references to `Image.memory` when searching on the web, but not of this error, nor of it being deprecated.  How do I get the `Image.memory` method??

Comment: @kris Have you imported import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

Answer (score 26):

```
Uint8List _bytesImage;

String _imgString = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg.....';

_bytesImage = Base64Decoder().convert(_imgString);

Image.memory(_bytesImage)
```

Comment: How do I use this on a CircleAvatar background Image? I have tried several things including `backgroundImage: Image.memory(_bytesImage);`

Comment: Nevermind, I found that I could just add `.image` to the end there and it worked: `backgroundImage: Image.memory(_bytesImage).image;`

Answer (score 12):

To open a camera photo (temporary folder), editing a file and then turning it into Base64:

**Code:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ImageProcess;

File file = File(imagePath);
final _imageFile = ImageProcess.decodeImage(
  file.readAsBytesSync(),
);

...edit file...

String base64Image = base64Encode(ImageProcess.encodePng(_imageFile));
```

**Decode and show:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ImageProcess;

final _byteImage = Base64Decoder().convert(base64Image);
Widget image = Image.memory(_byteImage)
```

Answer (score 10):

import

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
```

from screen load the data and assign to this variable

```
    Uint8List _bytes;
  _bytes = Base64Decoder().convert("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANgAAA......");
```

In code tree structure widget

```
Image.memory(_bytes)
```

Answer (score 5):

With this simple method i could set an image in flutter. The image attribute is the base64 image as string, example:

```
TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb2
```

Try the next:

```
Widget getImagenBase64(String imagen) {
    _imageBase64 = imagen;
    const Base64Codec base64 = Base64Codec();
    if (_imageBase64 == null) return new Container();
    bytes = base64.decode(_imageBase64);
    return Image.memory(
          bytes,
          width: 200,
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
       
    );
  }
```

I hope this work for you. Happy coding.

Comment: This is a bad practice to create a widget and return it in a function. Create a stateless widget which take your 'String imagen' as attributes and return your Image.memory

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                child: Image.memory(
                  base64Decode(widget.imgBase64 ?? ''),
                  gaplessPlayback: true,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
```

Comment: gaplessPlayback: true, helps to load the image

Answer (score 2):

Supposing we have a DataURL stored in a String of a format similar to the following:

```
String dataUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk...";
```

A simple solution exists to render this as an Image via `Uri`:

```
Image.memory(
    Uri.parse(dataUrl).data?.contentAsBytes()
    ?? Uint8List(0),
)
```

This is a null-safe solution, and can be easily modified into the following for older versions of Dart:

```
Image.memory(Uri.parse(dataUrl).data.contentAsBytes())
```

Answer (score 0):

Do check the type using runtimeType, In my case it was String.
My function was returning Future<<U'intList>> i changed it to Future<<s'tring>> and used Image.Memory like this: Image.memory(base64Decode(_imageBytes!)

Here is my full code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'getResponseFromNodeApi.dart';
import 'getResponseFromStabilityAi.dart';

class MyImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyImageWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyImageWidgetState createState() => _MyImageWidgetState();
}

class _MyImageWidgetState extends State<MyImageWidget> {
  String? _imageBytes;
  String? _errorMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _generateImage();
  }

  Future<void> _generateImage() async {
    setState(() {
      _imageBytes = null;
      _errorMessage = null;
    });

    try {
      // final bytes = await getResponseFromStabilityAi();
      final bytes = await getResponseFromNodeApi(textPrompt: 'light House');
      // List<int> bytes2 = utf8.encode(bytes as String);
      setState(() {
        _imageBytes = bytes;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        print(e);
        _errorMessage = 'Failed to generate image: $e';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Generated Image'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _imageBytes != null
            ? Image.memory(base64Decode(_imageBytes!))
            : _errorMessage != null
            ? Text(_errorMessage!)
            : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

    final time = DateTime.now().toIso8601String().replaceAll('.', ':');
    final name = 'signature_$time.png';
    
    final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    final File file = File("$dir/$name.png");
    
    // Upload it to server or download to your local.
    await file.writeAsBytes(img_base64!);
```

Hope it help!