# How can I get android drawables in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Flutters platform channel supports types like null, int, double, string, list, and map. But how can one get platform specific types like drawables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to convert your `Drawables` into a `Bitmap` and then convert the `Bitmap` into a base64 string and send it over the platform channel and convert the image back using the `Image.memory` constructor in Flutter. I'm not sure about the limitations on string size through the platform channels, but it should work as long as your images aren't huge.

Here are the answers I referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9224180/8338783 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146008/8338783

Comment: Thanks Spencer. This seems to work. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/drawable/versions/0.1.0).

```
import 'package:drawable/drawable.dart';

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Image(image: DrawableImage("drawable_id")),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Where "drawable_id" is the last part in R.drawable.drawable_id