# Flutter Persist Image in SQFLite

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, dart

i tried a lot but didnt find an Answer for my Problem or couldnt adapt it (Im not so deep in Flutter).

I have an Diary where i store the Entries as Text. This works very well!
So, i wanted to add an Camera/Image Picker where you can add an Picture to the Diary Entry and save it with the Text in SQFLite.
So the Camera/Image Picker works also really well. But i cant persist the Image. Everytime i reopen the Diary Entry, there is no Image.
Below is my Code:

This is my Page, where i add the Diary Entries. (I sorted it out, for a better view on it

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io' as Io;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
///import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';
import 'package:fischapp/Impressum.dart';
import 'package:fischapp/ReadTodoScreen.dart';
import 'package:fischapp/TimeDate.dart';
import 'package:fischapp/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';
import 'Todo.dart';
import 'DatabaseHelper.dart';
import 'ImageUploadModel.dart';
import 'dart:convert';





class DetailTodoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/detailTodoScreen';
  final Todo todo;

  const DetailTodoScreen({Key key, this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CreateTodoState(todo);


}


class _CreateTodoState extends State<DetailTodoScreen> {
  Todo todo;
  final descriptionTextController = TextEditingController();
  final titleTextController = TextEditingController();



  _CreateTodoState(this.todo);



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (todo != null) {
      descriptionTextController.text = todo.content;
      titleTextController.text = todo.title;
    }
    }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    descriptionTextController.dispose();
    titleTextController.dispose();
  }


  Future<File> imageFile;




  File _image;
  @override
  void initState4() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void open_camera()
  async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });

  }
  void open_gallery()
  async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }


  File _avatarImg;

  void _getImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) {
    ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: source,
      maxWidth: 400.0,
      maxHeight: 400.0,
    ).then((File image) {
      _avatarImg = image;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Neuer Tagebucheintrag'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: "Titel"),
              maxLines: 1,
              controller: titleTextController,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: "Kurzbeschreibung"),
              maxLines: 5,
              controller: descriptionTextController,
            ),
          ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
            child: Text("Open Camera", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            onPressed: (){

              open_camera();

            },),
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.limeAccent,

            child:Text("Open Gallery", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
            onPressed: (){
              open_gallery();
            },
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.black12,
            height: 500.0,
            width: 900.0,
            child: _image == null ? Text("Hier wird das Bild dargestellt!") : Image.file(_image),
          ),
          ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.check),
          onPressed: () async {
            _saveTodo(titleTextController.text, descriptionTextController.text);
            setState(() {});
          }),
    );
  }

  _saveTodo(String title, String content)
        async {
     if (todo == null) {
      DatabaseHelper.instance.insertTodo(Todo(
          title: titleTextController.text,
          content: descriptionTextController.text,

      ));
      Navigator.pop(context, "Your todo has been saved.");
    } else {
      await DatabaseHelper.instance
          .updateTodo(Todo(id: todo.id, title: title, content: content));
      Navigator.pop(context);
      setState(() {
        ReadTodoScreen();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I store the Description and Title as Text with Controller and give it to the sqflite.
With the FloatingActionButton, i call the saveTodo Function to store it.
The Function saveTodo call then the DataBaseHelper.

Here my DatabaseHelper Class.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'Todo.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  //Create a private constructor
  DatabaseHelper._();

  static const databaseName = 'todos_database.db';
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._();
  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      return await initializeDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }

  initializeDatabase() async {
    return await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), databaseName),
        version: 1, onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE todos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, title TEXT, content TEXT");
    });
  }

  insertTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.insert(Todo.TABLENAME, todo.toMap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    return res;
  }

  Future<List<Todo>> retrieveTodos() async {
    final db = await database;

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query(Todo.TABLENAME);

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Todo(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        title: maps[i]['title'],

      );
    });
  }

  updateTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final db = await database;

    await db.update(Todo.TABLENAME, todo.toMap(),
        where: 'id = ?',
        whereArgs: [todo.id],
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }

  deleteTodo(int id) async {
    var db = await database;
    db.delete(Todo.TABLENAME, where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

At least, the ToDo Class where the Variables are initialized:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

class Todo {
  final int id;
  final String content;
  final String title;

  static const String TABLENAME = "todos";

  Todo({this.id, this.content, this.title});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'id': id, 'content': content, 'title': title};
  }
}
```

I tried to store it as BLOB but i didnt get it worked. Neither as BASE64 String. :(
I heard about the Size increasement with BASE64 Strings but that doesnt matter.

I hope, thats all you need.
Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Shared Preferences or Hive packages for saving image or other big values than String. Sqflite is not more comfortable to do that.

- [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
- [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)

Examples of saving the image to local storage:

1. [First Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2X_TCU2n47w)
2. [Second Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKvgVu3ihkM)

---

And if these solutions don't work for you, You can check another StackOverflow question where was answered; how to save the image to local storage with Sqflite. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170790/how-to-save-image-data-to-sqflite-database-in-flutter-for-persistence)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but i try to solve it with sqflite. It would take very long to build it new with shared preference or do you have an (working) example?

Comment: You're welcome! did you asked an example of shared preferences?

Comment: Here, I have pasted 2 youtube videos about how to save the image to local storage with Shared Preferences.  And down below u can see another StackOverflow questions link where answered; how to save the image to local storage with Sqflite.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the Solution from your Link but it doesnt work for me. 
I can try your YT Videos. Thanks!

Comment: You’re Welcome dude!

Comment: Try found the solution for you in the another stackOverflov question which one i added on answer.