# Flutter - Save network image to sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Hello guys i want to safe an image in my [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) database i tried many thing but i only get errors like invalid image data or something else.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

String _base64 ="";

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      "https://www.mera-petfood.com/files/_processed_/a/4/csm_iStock-521697453_69acb65057.jpg"));

  _base64 = base64Encode(response.bodyBytes);
  
};


Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(_base64);


return Scaffold(
  appBar: null,
  body: SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("open database"),
          onPressed: () async {},
        ),

        Image.memory(bytes),
        Text(model.base64String(bytes)),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

thats my actual code but i only get this Exception:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data
```

Why is it not working i cant solve it?

Comment: In my experience I do not like to save images in the database, I prefer to save the path of the image in the database and that image then store it in a folder of the app itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is not saving to sqflite, but your anonymous function is never called. So, the `_base64` is always empty string.

First, this not works:

```
() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      "https://www.mera-petfood.com/files/_processed_/a/4/csm_iStock-521697453_69acb65057.jpg"));

  _base64 = base64Encode(response.bodyBytes);
  
};
```

because it never called.

It should be (see the last part with `()`:

```
() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      "https://www.mera-petfood.com/files/_processed_/a/4/csm_iStock-521697453_69acb65057.jpg"));

  _base64 = base64Encode(response.bodyBytes);
  
}();
```

Second, you should not add the anonymous function to `build` because it will be called repeatedly. Try moving it as class scope function. Something like this (You need to use [stateful widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive#creating-a-stateful-widget)):

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    String _base64 ="";
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      ...
    }

    void getImage() async {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          "https://www.mera-petfood.com/files/_processed_/a/4/csm_iStock-521697453_69acb65057.jpg"));
    
    
       setState(() {
          _base64 = base64Encode(response.bodyBytes);
       });

    };    
}
```

then, called it initState:

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   getImage();
}
```

and, finally, use it to your widget in `build` method:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: null,
      body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("open database"),
              onPressed: () async {},
            ),
    
            // When _base64 is empty string, then it means
            // image is on the way. 
            _base64.isEmpty? CircularProgressIndicator(): Image.memory(base64Decode(_base64)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can do this.

1. Store it as a file
2. Store it as a blob

For second one, You need to read about `blob` first. So the way you are going to do this is `Make a blob of the image and then save it in the database`. Now you may ask what is a `blob`?

Blob stands for `binary large object` which is a collection of binary data stored as a single entity. `Blobs` are typically `images`, `audio` or other `multimedia` objects, though sometimes binary executable code is stored as a `blob`.

Please read the following articles:

[Saving images: files or blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347461/saving-images-files-or-blobs)

[How to save image data to sqflite database in flutter for persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170790/how-to-save-image-data-to-sqflite-database-in-flutter-for-persistence)