# Undefined name 'BASE64'

Tags: dart, flutter

Why does `import 'dart:convert' show BASE64`; give me an error?

```
import 'dart:convert' show BASE64;
    
var output = BASE64.encode(digest.bytes)
```

> Undefined name 'BASE64'.

Thanks

Comment: You have a duplicated question. Check here the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876399/flutter-base64-class-not-found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart 2 such SCREAMING_CASE constant names were changed to lowerCamelCase

Just change `BASE64` to `base64`. Similar with `JSON` -> `json` and a few more.