# How do I convert an image to base64 and base64 to image? The way I do it doesn't work

Tags: dart, flutter, decode, encode

This is an example code.

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
var stringBytes = base64.encode(image.readAsBytesSync());
var bytes = base64.decode(stringBytes);
var newImage = new File.fromRawPath(bytes);
```

```
I/flutter (14608): The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (14608): Cannot open file, path = '����*�Exif
I/flutter (14608): 
I/flutter (14608): 
I/flutter (14608): Business
I/flutter (14608): 11:42:34
I/flutter (14608): �
I/flutter (14608):  
I/flutter (14608): ��
I/flutter (14608): ��
I/flutter (14608): %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������
I/flutter (14608): ��
I/flutter (14608): $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������
I/flutter (14608): ��ت���U-%�����^
I/flutter (14608): }�m���
I/flutter (14608): u���V�N6R���
I/flutter (14608): j_8}W,1�ڹ�?ܻw^��� ��6��ꗚm���E[ϓ�������>���X�W��y������=�[!��2!ډ�'8�Mk^ܾ��eS�
```

and the list of unknown characters continues.

What am I doing wrong?

I want to convert it in base64 because I am going to add it in a database.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146008/735226

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert BASE64 string into Image with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145472/how-to-convert-base64-string-into-image-with-flutter)

Comment: none of that things work

Answer (score 2):

Nah, you're passing the content of the image to create a new file with the content as raw path, this cannot work.

`new File.fromRawPath` does, according to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/File/File.fromRawPath.html):

> Creates a File object from a raw path, that is, a sequence of bytes as
>   represented by the OS.

What you want to do is to create a file and store the content to that file, this can be done like that ([Source](https://www.dartlang.org/server/io-library-tour#writing-file-contents)):

```
var imageFile = File('myimage.jpg');
var sink = imageFile.openWrite();
sink.write(bytes);
await sink.flush();
await sink.close();
```