# Dart (Flutter) Image to base64 conversion

Tags: flutter, dart, base64

Trying to convert an image to base64 encoded bytes using Dart 2.5.0

I'm using the code as below

```
List<int> imageBytes = _imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
Uint8List decoded = base64Decode(base64Image);

print(base64Image);
print(decoded);
```

Output looks like below

```
I/flutter ( 8744): 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
D/EGL_emulation( 8744): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe63a2320: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe9be0f30)
I/flutter ( 8744): [255, 216, 255, 225, 0, 106, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 20, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 218, 135, 105, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 62, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 146, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 255, 192, 0, 17, 8, 2, 218, 5, 20, 3, 1, 34, 0, 2, 17, 1, 3, 17, 1, 255, 196, 0, 31, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 1, 2, 3,
```

I looked at similar posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977615/flutter-convert-image-to-base64-and-base64-string-to-image) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233038/how-do-i-convert-an-image-to-base64-and-base64-to-image-the-way-i-do-it-doesnt)...

I'm using the data to make an API call to OpenALPR recognize_bytes endpoint, but I get a `400: Bad Request error`

Why I convert the same image to base64 online, the output looks different. Online conversion looks like below:

```
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
```

The encoded text above works with my API call..

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: In what way does the output look different? What's the purpose of converting to B64 and then back again?

Comment: The online conversion returns more almost 10 times the chars than in the print statement. I thought this was related to the print statement truncating the text, but that should not have impacted my API call. The conversion back again was simply for testing. Kindly ignore that.

Comment: Have pasted the output from the online conversion above.