# Flutter Uint8list string from database render as Image

Tags: sql-server, laravel, image, flutter, uint8list

**Scenario:**

- I have a signature pad and its points (List) saves to SQL server.
- I fetch it from database and display it to another screen.

**Flutter Save Code**

I will just provide important code that I think are relevant.

```
// This is save button
onPressed() {
   data = {
     'Signature' : _fbKey.currentState.value['signature'].toString()
   }
}

// trigger _save function
if (_fbKey.currentState.saveAndValidate()) {
  _save(data);
}

// _save function
_save(data) async {
   final response = await http.post('url here..', body: data);
}
```

**Laravel Codes**
I will provide code that I also think are relevant

```
Route::middleware('admin')->post('link...', function (Request $request) {
   $user = new User;

   $user->Signature= $request->Signature;

   $user->save();

   return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Success',
        'data' => $user
    ], 200);
});
```

**Flutter Fetch Code**

```
getData() async {
   final response = await http.get('url goes here');

   var signRes = jsonDecode(response.body);
   String rawSign = signRes['data']['Signature'];
   print(rawSign); // output [137, ....so on]

   List<int> list = rawSign.codeUnits;
   print(list); // the output that I expected suddenly change to [91, ..... so on]

   Uint8List signature = Uint8List.fromList(list); 

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   .......
   .......
      child: Container(
         child: Image.memory(signature);         
      )
   )
}
```

**SQL Server**

```
column : Signature
datatype: nvarchar(max)
```

Exception I got:

> could not instantiate image codec

**Question**

- As you can see, the point(List) that I got from Signature pad is legit points(List) but I convert it to `toString()` when saving it because `Flutter` is throwing exception saying cannot cast `Uint8Arrat to String`. So, is it possible to get *Stringed List points* from Database and not convert it to `.codeUnits`? Because when doing that, the `value changes from what expected`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally get it working thanks to [the other SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145472/how-to-convert-base64-string-into-image-with-flutter#comment79281031_46146008)

Basically, I convert my data to *base64* first before saving into database.

```
data = {
  'Signature' : base64Encode(_fbKey.currentState.value['signature'])
}
```

And then convert it back to its original form

```
var signRes = jsonDecode(response.body);
String rawSign = signRes['data']['Signature'];
Uint8List signature = base64Decode(rawSign);
```

And finally, boom. The image successfully renders in the app as expected.