# How to decode Base64 String to Image file with flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I am actually trying to convert an Image file to Base64 and decode Base64 String to Image file in Dart/Flutter. Indeed, my application takes pictures with the camera plugin and then, saves it in a database as a Base64 String (because I don't know any other way but may be there is more relevant ways to store several images?).

I encode with this code :

```
            final path = join(
              (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
              '${DateTime.now()}.png',
            );
            await _controller.takePicture(path);
            final bytes = File(path).readAsBytesSync();
            String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);

            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(imageAnalysed: img64),
              ),
            );
```

And decode with this one :

```
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageAnalysed;
  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key key, this.imageAnalysed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final decodedBytes = base64Decode(imageAnalysed);
    var fileImg= File("testImage.png");
    fileImg..writeAsBytesSync(decodedBytes);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Display the Picture')),
      body: Image.file(fileImg),
    );
  }
}
```

But there is this error :

```
The following FileSystemException was thrown building DisplayPictureScreen(dirty):
Cannot open file, path = 'testImage.png' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)
```

How can I solve my problem and get an image from the Base64 String ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146008/11550065 Someone has already answer this question

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but using Image.memory doesn't seem to solve my problem because I need a file to crop the images when it is necessary (with this package https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) and Image.memory only gives Image type and not a File. This is why I try to use `writeAsBytesSync`.

Comment: The error explains your problem ("OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30"), which has nothing to do with base64 decoding.  You don't seem to supply an absolute path to the file that you write to.  What is the current directory?  Are you trying to write to the root directory?

Comment: Actually I'm new to flutter so I don't really know where is the file I write to. I thought `var fileImg= File("testImage.png")`created a temporary file with a particular directory. So to solve the problem I should use `path_provider` to implement `getTemporaryDirectory()` and create a temporary file at this directory ? Or is there something simpler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `path_provider` to get `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` and use `bool` `isLoading` to control show image when write file finish

code snippet

```
 void writeFile() async {
    final decodedBytes = base64Decode(widget.imageAnalysed);
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    fileImg = File('${directory.path}/testImage.png');
    print(fileImg.path);
    fileImg.writeAsBytesSync(List.from(decodedBytes));

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      writeFile();
    });

 ...      
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Image.file(fileImg);
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageAnalysed;
  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key key, this.imageAnalysed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DisplayPictureScreenState createState() => _DisplayPictureScreenState();
}

class _DisplayPictureScreenState extends State<DisplayPictureScreen> {
  File fileImg;
  bool isLoading = true;

  void writeFile() async {
    final decodedBytes = base64Decode(widget.imageAnalysed);
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    fileImg = File('${directory.path}/testImage.png');
    print(fileImg.path);
    fileImg.writeAsBytesSync(List.from(decodedBytes));

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      writeFile();
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Image.file(fileImg);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String base64String =
      '''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''';
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            DisplayPictureScreen(imageAnalysed: base64String),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, it works so well ! The code is very understandable and complete,I didn't know `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` but I'm sure I will use it again. Thank you very much !

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.