# Flutter : How to display data:image/jpeg;base64

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everyone i try display this image data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=

in my flutter app using

```
image.network()
```

but its format is not supported

how can I display it  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert BASE64 string into Image with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145472/how-to-convert-base64-string-into-image-with-flutter)

Comment: Edit your question bro just ask "how to convert base64 to image"

Comment: this is the sample small image data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ImageProcess;

final _byteImage = Base64Decoder().convert(base64Image);
Widget image = Image.memory(_byteImage)
```

Comment: thnx for reply .. i get this error : Invalid character (at character 5)
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...

Comment: it work now thnx bro :))))

Comment: Do you extract the string first to get the character after comma? @SparkatJKS