# Dart: The method 'memory' isn't defined for the type 'Image'

Tags: flutter, image, dart, base64

I have a base64 string of an image, and I want to make a method to convert that to a Flutter `Image`.

There is an [existing SO question asking exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145472/how-to-convert-base64-string-into-image-with-flutter), however all of the answers there make use of the `Image.memory` constructor for the `Image`, and when I go to do that I get the following error:

> The method 'memory' isn't defined for the type 'Image'. Try correcting
> the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
> 'memory'.

Searching for "[The method 'memory' isn't defined for the type 'Image'.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20method%20%27memory%27%20isn%27t%20defined%20for%20the%20type%20%27Image%27.%22&sxsrf=APwXEdeDLxclzXxxC3boAYCdYefJ4M4VMg%3A1684193832934&ei=KMJiZKDZOILiseMPlJiX-AI&ved=0ahUKEwigjZT5vvj-AhUCcWwGHRTMBS8Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22The%20method%20%27memory%27%20isn%27t%20defined%20for%20the%20type%20%27Image%27.%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQA0oECEEYAVAAWABg0AJoAXAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQDAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)" on Google gives 0 results.

There is definitely an `Image.memory` constructor: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html

This is my code: `return Image.memory(base64Decode(base64DataString));`

[image]

I am certain I'm just having a blond moment here, but I am stumped and asking for help nonetheless.

Why am I getting this error when trying to call `Image.memory`?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `Image` class from Flutter and not some other `Image` class with the same name?

Comment: That was it - you champion @jamesdlin !! -- I was using `Image` from `dart:ui`, not from `package:flutter/material.dart` ... go ahead and post an answer and I'll mark it as correct .. I'll even fill in the details if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you encounter errors like this, you're almost certainly unwittingly using a different class than the one you think but that happens to have the same name.

Your IDE should be able to tell you where the definition for the `Image` class is coming from.  It's not the one from the Flutter Widgets library.

Comment: Specifically for me, I had added `Image` by hovering on the word "Image" in VSCode and clicking "Quick Fix..." .. but I chose "`Import library 'dart:ui'`" instead of "`Import library package:flutter/material.dart`"